# Potentially dangerous request loads the page

Tags: xss, .net, url

I hosted an application in ASP.NET 4.0 webforms.

When I am browsing `hostname/DressDetail.aspx?<script>alert(313)</script>&category=1&code=76` it is showing an error message like:

> A potentially dangerous `Request.QueryString` value was detected from the client `(="alert(313)`

I am expecting the same error message as above when I am browsing `hostname/DressDetail.aspx?<script>alert(313)</script>=1&category=1&code=76`, but it loads the page. The only difference is an extra `=1` in the latter url.

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze what is happening here by looking at ASP.NET WebForms code.

### First example, w/o `=1`

> [HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (="alert(1)c__DisplayClass280_0.b__0(String key, String value) +22
>      System.Web.HttpValueCollection.EnsureKeyValidated(String key) +9904693
>      System.Web.HttpValueCollection.GetValues(String name) +17
>      System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +99

If we run the code we can see that the exception originates in `EnsureKeyValidated` but we can get there from `GetValues`, from `DeterminePostBackMode`. So if you check there we see this:

```
      string[] values = nameValueCollection.GetValues((string) null);
```

so it's look like what we get here is retrieving all the values that are key-less. So the above query could be rewritten to the form `null=<script>alert(313)</script>&`. So the script is passed to be the **value** for an null/empty **key**.

### Second example, w/ `=1`

In here you're making the **key** to be equal to the script, and the **value** for that key to be 1. The key's are encoded before they are passed to the server so this would not be an issue.

[image]

If you want to replicate the error, you could pass `a=<script>alert(313)</script>` and you would get the same error just originating from a different place:

> [HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (a="alert(1)c__DisplayClass280_0.b__0(String key, String value) +22
>      System.Web.HttpValueCollection.EnsureKeyValidated(String key) +9904693
>      System.Web.HttpValueCollection.GetValues(Int32 index) +29
>      System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ToString(Boolean urlencoded, IDictionary excludeKeys) +206
>      System.Web.UI.Page.get_ClientQueryString() +411

If you need to you can control what is being [denied](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/denyquerystringsequences/index).